# What is Mikage's status (in the spirit/god world) after he passes the Tochigami Crest to Nanami? Is he still a god?

Tags: kamisama-kiss

Mikage passed the Tochigami Crest (the symbol of divinity and ownership of his temple) to Nanami, but obviously retained several of his powers.

> Like when he converted Nanami's dress into a butterfly pattern before her ritual dance in the end of 1st season.

He is no longer a god, because

> he did not attend the Izumo meeting in the second season.

and also because

> the host god of the Izumo meeting [name pending] specifically states that Mikage is hard to find because he is no longer a god.

So, what is Mikage as of the Izumo meeting? He is not a god. Is he a youkai, a fallen deity, or what?

EDIT: In the episode S2E4 "The Goddess Makes Her Second Romantic Confession", Mikage is shown at the god's summit closing banquet. So he has some divine status, but the divine familiars of Nanami and also the shrine spirits are there too, so that banquet is not deity-exclusive.

Answer (score 3):

It's not as present in the anime as in the manga, but Mikage takes the shape of a butterfly and you can see him fly around in the manga at all the important events and otherwise. He's constantly monitoring Nanami.

I believe he is still a kami deity, just not the deity in charge any more. I've interpreted it as the crest being a sign of her taking on the godly responsibilities and in all practical manners is a god, even though she is still human. He's still the shrine's god, he's just handed over the practical responsibilities to Nanami.

Your race doesn't change just because you gave away or received a profession.

This is my interpretation at least.