# Have Mikage's powers diminished?

Tags: kamisama-kiss

At the very beginning of *Kamisama Kiss*, Mikage gave Nanami spiritual powers and made her the Kami of Mikage shrine, but did he do this without losing any of his own power? Is there any evidence that his powers have diminished? If so, how much has he been weakened? Is there any evidence to the contrary?

Related question with no satisfactory answers: [What is Mikage's status (in the spirit/god world) after he passes the Tochigami Crest to Nanami? Is he still a god?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/18920/what-is-mikages-status-in-the-spirit-god-world-after-he-passes-the-tochigami)

I'm looking for an answer with more evidence than the one for this question and I would like to see more of a focus on Mikage's power and abilities rather than his status.